# How can I change the login screen theme in GDM?

Tags: themes, gdm, login-screen

How can I change the Login screen theme? Is there a graphical way or no?

Comment: You may be interested in this themeable alternative to GDM: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143192/how-can-i-replace-lightdm-with-mdm

Comment: Wow!  Thank you!  Not exactly GDM, but I can theme it and it works well!  Much better than other solutions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this command in the terminal:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow
```

Logout, and **you will be prompted with the Appearance window**. change the theme as you change it for the desktop, and login back, and type this command:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop
```

That's it.

Comment: Instead of logging out, you can also use "Switch User".

Comment: Does not work with 11.10 or later as they use LightDM instead of GDM.

Comment: Does not work with Ubuntu 17.10 where GDM is default again. A working example can be found on https://didrocks.fr/2017/09/11/ubuntu-gnome-shell-in-artful-day-11/

Answer (score 11):

This depends on what you want to do with the login screen. You can configure some basic options in the Login Screen Settings app ([System/Administration/Login Screen](https://imgur.com/HUygl.png)) - whether a user should be automatically logged in, the default session etc.

However to change the login screen more graphically [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) can be used to change the background, logo etc.

[image: Ubuntu Tweak - Login settings]

Comment: It doesn't allow you to change any fonts, font-hinting, pointers, selected-item colors or icons. Just the wallpaper and the logo .

Answer (score 2):

U can use GDMtweak to change theme and Icon. see the link http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/change-gdm-theme-background-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a graphical tool to automate the process but is not overly complicated to change the theme of gdm.

Take a look at [Gnome-Look GDM](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xsortmode=down&page=0&xcontentmode=150), most of the themes there come with good instructions on how to install them.

Comment: I think those themes are for an older version of GDM than what is shipped with Ubuntu now. Those will probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a graphical tool for this. It's called GDM2Setup. You can get it from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/gdm2setup

Answer (score 0):

Theme Support for GDM has been terminated since UBUNTU 9.Sorry..!!

Comment: What?  Can I change any options at all?  Who says? NOOOOOOOO!!!!!

Comment: You cannot change any thene or any option related to its looks...What is offered is what you will have to accept..You may consider reinstalling *lightdm*

Comment: Yeah... I can't, because I can't log in from LightDM (it's borked in 12.04 x64).  Well, thanks. ;(  (But where is this info from?) (I would still like to know.)

Comment: Hmmm... thanks for the info.  Interesting, my GDM looks different than that, more square and such.  I just configured gdm from terminal login, and didn't install anything.  Darn.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the image you want to use into the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` folder.
2. Run

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
   ```
3. Search for the following section

   ```
   #lockDialogGroup { 

   background: #2e3436 url(noise-texture.png); 

   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   ```
4. Change the name of the image to your image and set background to repeat or no-repeat.
5. Save the file.
6. Logout and your new background is there.

This works for Ubuntu GNOME, for other flavours it might not work.