# Change Login Window Appearance

Tags: fonts, gdm, login-screen, appearance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the login screen theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193/how-can-i-change-the-login-screen-theme)

Is there any way to change the appearance of the login window (specifically including the font hinting settings)?

It would be nice if I could somehow "sudo" as the login window's account, then change the settings like that.

Comment: Yes indeed, it seems like that one answers my question too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather hacky but just tested it on Natty and found it did the trick.

1. `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow`
2. logout
3. Login screen will come up, with the Appearance prefs panel displayed.
4. Choose new appearance settings
5. Login
6. `sudo unlink /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop`

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal:

```
xhost +
gksudo -u gdm gnome-appearance-properties
```

It will display an error about gnome settings daemon not running but it should be able to apply the changes anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It seems to be exactly what I need, but for some reason it isn't allowing me to change the smoothing settings. (I click the radio buttons but they don't get selected.) What could be the problem?