# Changing the login screen design?

Tags: 11.04, gdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the login screen theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193/how-can-i-change-the-login-screen-theme)

How do I change how the login screen looks in Ubuntu 11.04? I want to change both the background and the design of the grey rectangle (where the login form is) in the center. I've found some sites explaining how do do it for 10.04, but only for changing the background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool called **GDM Tweaker**:

> GDM Tweaker is a very simple application that allows tweaking the GDM login screen look: change the GDM background image, hide the username list, enable Compiz and change the GDM login screen icon or GTK theme.

[image]

**To install GDM Tweaker in Ubuntu 11.04:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:madnessmike/madnessmike
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdm-tweaker
```

**Note**: To be able to change the GDM Background / Theme you must place the **images** (must be only `.png` or `.jpg`) into `/usr/share/backgrounds/` and the Themes into `/usr/share/themes/` for **GTK themes** and `/usr/share/icons/` for the **icons**.
To be able to copy the themes / backgrounds to these folders, open Nautilus as root using `gksu nautilus` .

**Source** : [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/change-gdm-theme-background-in-ubuntu.html).

Answer (score 1):

Download Ubuntu-Tweak from http://ubuntu-tweak.com/ and go down to 'Login Settings' and you can change the logo and the background image.

Comment: I also want to change the area behind the logo.

Comment: You can't, not on GDM.You can only change the background and the GDM theme.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install anything, you can change the appearance by running:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/
```

Then log out and you will see the Appearance Properties window from which you can change the theme, background and fonts.

Once you are happy, log back in and run:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the background behind the login screen used to be (in the ol days - ok last time I messed with it) contained in file system/usr/share/backgrounds

Fire up sudo nautilus and navigate through to there if you can and let us know how you get on.

Afraid I am not on my ubuntu pc at the mo so cannot give the abolute link

Comment: It is now on /usr/share/backgrounds.