# Complete LinuxMint theme for ubuntu

Tags: 11.04, themes, mint

I am using the Ubuntu 11.04 with unity from the day of it's release. I am not at all happy with the usability of unity. Like no minimize by clicking on the icon on the task bar, menus at the top bar etc. Specially the new application menu, it's hell lot difficult to find an application. Recently I tried the LinuxMint ubuntu version and I am quite happy with the GUI and overall look of the distro, until I had install the update in the new LinuxMint. I faced some video issue, which I was not able to resolve even with the help of the LinuxMint community.

Again I revert back to Ubuntu. I tried the Ubuntu Classic but I feel it is wasting a lot of screen space in my small 15" laptop.

So, is there any way I can get the LinuxMint complete theme in Ubuntu 11.04. I know there are repos to install the MintMenu but I need the at least same theme of LinuxMint desktop look and feel in ubuntu like single task bar bottom and MintMenu.

Comment: Log out , choose Classic and download the Mint-X theme, move the panel, add the Mintmenu...

Comment: @Abhijeet - if you want the complete look and feel of linux mint - just install linux mint!  Why do you want to convert ubuntu into linux mint?

Comment: @fossfreedom.. I have mentioned it my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install all of the Mint specific packages by adding the official Mint repositories. You can do this by adding:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ katya main upstream import
```

as a software source.

You may want to make sure you have all of the repositories that come with Mint by default. You can do this by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. You can then edit the text file to make sure each of these lines exist:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ katya main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ natty partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ natty free non-free
```

Once you have done this, open Synaptic Package Manager and click reload. You can then install the packages you want.

Install the package `mintmenu` to install the menu.

To get the default themes install: `mint-artwork-common`, `mint-artwork-gnome`, `mint-x-icons`, `mint-x-theme` and `mint-elementary-icons`.

To get the default wallpapers install: `mint-backgrounds-katya` and `mint-backgrounds-katya-extra`.

Once these are installed you can delete your top panel and modify the applets on your bottom panel. By default, the bottom panel in Mint has the following applets (in order left-right):

- Mint Menu
- Show Desktop
- Window List
- Notification Area
- Application Indicators
- Clock

You can also change your theme and background to Mint ones if you wish.

Comment: Great answer, but I'm pretty certain there is no need to add the mediabuntu non-free and Canonical partner repositories in order to achieve this.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. Completely overhauled the Ubuntu to Mint theme. This is what I am looking for. One small problem, my Ubuntu Login screen also been replaced by the Mint login screen. Is there any way I can revert the only the login screen to the Ubuntu login screen.

Comment: @andrewsomething - some of the Mint (meta)packages depend on packages in medibuntu (not the theme ones though). Abhijeet see http://askubuntu.com/questions/52245/changing-the-login-screen-design/52297#52297

Comment: After setting mint theme I faced the same video issue as I faced in Linux mint. I resolved the video issue by replacing the compiz with metacity. Then I found there is a sound lag in video play back. To resolve it I removed the pluseaudio and it started working fine. But now while I am trying to open the sound config it is showing sound system not responding. :(  Another problem is that I can't find the "ubuntu software center" in the mint Menu. I tried to run it using synpase but it did not worked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a theme repo from the webupd8 ppa,this will give icons,themes,and a mint menu.

webupd8 themes ppa
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/announcing-webupd8-themes-ppa.html

webupd8 ppa
https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8

overview of software
http://www.webupd8.org/p/ubuntu-ppas-by-webupd8.html