# Changing Wallpaper on 12.04 Login Screen

Tags: 12.04, software-center, ubuntu-netbook

I'm using this [link](http://joesteiger.com/2011/11/06/change-lightdm-login-background-ubuntu-11-10/) but seems to be not working on 12.04, here's the Terminal message below: Are there other softwares/tips for changing the login screen? I'm also using [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52245/changing-the-login-screen-design) but seems outdated.

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/claudiocn/slm/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/claudiocn/slm/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/claudiocn/slm/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
law@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install simple-lightdm-manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package simple-lightdm-manager
```

Comment: You can use Ubuntu Tweak to change the background of your login screen. Hare's a [guide](http://askubuntu.com/a/140918/37006).

Answer (score 8):

Just change the background on the desktop, choose one of the pre-configured images, and that will do it.

[image]

If you want to use your own image then click on the + sign, add your image, and then change the permissions

[image]

on the image for group read and write and other to be read only.

And that will do it.  No need to use anything else.

Comment: I dunno maybe it's my own image, tried 3 images, still not working.

Comment: I had a problem with low resolution images.  Try using a high resolution image.  Need more help, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, what resolution would you recommend? I used 1440x900

Answer (score 3):

If your home folder is encrypted, the login screen software will not be able to access your photo folder.

My solution to this problem was to create a folder outside my home folder to store wallpapers.

```
cd /
sudo mkdir wallpaper
sudo chown USERNAME /wallpaper
sudo chgrp USERNAME /wallpaper
```

Copy your wallpapers to that folder. Then when you set a desktop background, the login background will change as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change your login screen , follow these steps:

The first thing we need to do is modify the **ubuntu.css** file located under ***/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme***. Open the Terminal application through Ubuntu Dash or by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+T**

Enter the following command to open the css file in gedit.

`$ sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

Search for the term ‘lockDialog’ by pressing **Ctrl+D** and entering this keyword in the search bar. This way you will be directed to the location where we want to make the required changes. This is the section of the file we will be editing:

You will see that the file noise-texture.png specifies the default image that Ubuntu uses as the lock and login screen background.

You need to replace the lines with the following ones:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
background: #2c001e url(file:///[fileLocation/filename.png]);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

Save this file by clicking the Save button located at the top right corner of the text editor.

Restart your computer for these changes to take effect.

Now when you log in to your system, you will be able to see the newly set up background instead of the default Ubuntu login image.

So, as you have seen, changing the login background is not as difficult as it seems. You simply need to edit the ubuntu.css file and restart the computer in order to make this supposedly technical customization.