# Ubuntu login screen wallpaper missing 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

I am new to Ubuntu and I tried to change my login screen wallpaper by using terminal according to this:

[Changing login screen wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313526/changing-login-screen-wallpaper-in-ubuntu-13-04)

At this time I did not know about ubuntu tweaks. However, I did not get the wallpaper and ended up with a purple dot screen as my login screen. I want to know how to revert back to my default login screen that comes when I first install ubuntu. Right now, even when I use ubuntu tweaks, it still does not update and end up with the purple dot screen. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this command (notice that `set` has been changed to `get` ):

`$ gsettings get com.canonical.unity-greeter background`

My output:

`$ gsettings get com.canonical.unity-greeter background
'/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'`

So I guess the default wallpaper can be set using:

`gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background '/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'`