# How to change Ubuntu login screen background without dconf-editor?

Tags: 14.04, lightdm

I am trying to change the Ubuntu login background which should be the same as the wallpaper, without installing dconf-editor or additional software. Is is possible?

Comment: Whatever you did using `dconf-editor` can be accomplished using the `gsettings` command line tool. So what did you do with `dconf-editor`?

Comment: Do you want it to be different from the wallpaper you see when logged in?

Comment: No it should be the same.

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/313526/changing-login-screen-wallpaper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to open your file manager (e.g. Nautilus) with root privileges:

```
sudo nautilus
```

And then copy the desired wallpaper to the following folder:

```
/usr/share/backgrounds
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. Ubuntu login screen uses your wallpaper by default. If it is not so, then I assume you have installed another desktop environment or somehow changed default settings. Just reinstall unity.