# Change the background of the login screen

Tags: lightdm, desktop-background

I installed Ubuntu Studio 15.10 and upon that:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now on the login screen, I have the default brownish Ubuntu default background.

- I tried this as root:

  ```
  sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
  sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
  gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background /usr/share/backgrounds/Tranquil_by_Pat_David.jpg
  ```

  But this didn't change anything.
- Also starting the `unity-control-center` as user lightdm and changing the background there had no effect.
- I also checked the rights of `/usr/share/backgrounds/Tranquil_by_Pat_David.jpg` which are globally readable.

Comment: This is a [Duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313526/changing-login-screen-wallpaper)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I tried everything in that question

Comment: Maybe a bit duplicate indeed, cause the answer was in one of the low voted answers: http://askubuntu.com/a/360008/34298

Comment: I've updated my answer, please refer

Answer (score 23):

The proper way of changing default `unity-greeter` background is through overriding `glib-2.0` schema, as specified in the [Lightdm Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)

The steps are as follows:

1. Create `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override` file with the following contents:

   ```
   [com.canonical.unity-greeter]
   draw-user-backgrounds=false
   background='/foo/wallpaper.png'
   ```
2. Run `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`
3. Reboot or login to TTY2  (accessed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>  ) and run `sudo service lightdm restart`

This has been tested on my Ubuntu 14.04

**Update: November 17 2015**

I have put together a script that simplifies the process of changing the greeter background. It has been tested in its final form on two versions of Ubuntu, 14.04 LTS (actual physical machine ) and 15.10 (Virtual Machine )
It can be found in [my GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/chgreeterbg.sh)

Comment: Thanks for your script! It, however, produces [this](http://i.imgur.com/IvHYY91.png) error when running.

Comment: @orschiro you have to call script with path to file. For example,  `sudo ./chgreeterbg.sh /home/user/Picture s/wallpaper1.png`

Comment: That works, thanks! Maybe you want to add this to your answer?

Comment: After running your script and rebooting, my [font settings have changed](http://i.imgur.com/vI9g3CZ.png). Do you know how I can restore them?

Comment: And after boot, I now get [this](http://i.imgur.com/HnB1Fwt.png) error message. Can this be related to the changes due to your script?

Comment: @orschiro The script doesn't deal with fonts, so i don't thing that's related. Use Unity Tweak Tool to reset your fonts. I don't know about the second error you're getting, but i doubt it's related also

Comment: Using Unity Tweak Tool to reset helped. Thank you Serg!

Comment: This also works for Ubuntu 16.04. Be careful about typos - I had a typo in the schema name within the .gschema.override file, which is the part between the brackets [ ], and as a result it was not properly loading. Once I fixed that I had the correct background.

Comment: Yup, works quite well on 16.04, i still use my script regularly

Answer (score 4):

It seems like all the gsettings have no effect in Ubuntu 15.10, (maybe because I installed Ubuntu Studio with xfce4 first).

I solved it by adding this line to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`:

```
background=/usr/share/backgrounds/Tranquil_by_Pat_David.jpg
```

or in one `sudo` command:

```
sudo su -c 'echo "background=/usr/share/backgrounds/Tranquil_by_Pat_David.jpg">>/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf'
```

Answer (score 0):

The non coder way is to use Ubuntu Tweak.  Still available per the method listed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770947/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-tweak-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Answer (score 0):

## Shotwell

For just the basic wallpaper changing feature, you don’t need to install any software, just `shotwell`.

Just launch the pre-installed Shotwell photo manager, choose the pictures you need (you may need to import them first), then go to Files -> Set as Desktop Slideshow. Click  "on lockscreen".

Finally set the time interval in next dialog as desired and done!

*source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/4-wallpaper-changer-ubuntu-18-04/*

Note: This does not work for the login screen any more in Ubuntu 19.04, but still for the dektop background.