# Error while attempt to change login screen background picture

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, desktop-background

Open a terminal and get root

```
sudo -i
```

(Type sudo password)

Allow the user lightdm to create a connection to the X server

```
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
```

Switch user to lightdm

```
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
```

Change the default background with a picture of your choice

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background '/foo/wallpaper.png'
```

i get this error :

**> (process:3178): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf:

> Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch
>   --autolaunch=c50417a6888605aa39e81e4c56aa8bba --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1**

Comment: Here's the way of changing [lightdm greeter background](http://askubuntu.com/a/694370/295286). It has been mentioned in the official ubuntu wiki. I've also put together a script that does the same thing, just lightly simpler. Let me know if you want complete answer posted here

Answer (score 0):

After switching to lightdm you should first issue this command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'true'
```

Resource: https://askubuntu.com/a/334992/488702