# How can I install Ubuntu tweak on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-tweak

I can't install Ubuntu tweak on 16.04.  I've had it on 4 previous versions of Ubuntu, so I know exactly what to do in order to install it, it just doesn't work on 16.04.

Is anyone having the same problem?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13):

Although the program is now [abandonware](http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-tweak-is-now-officially-dead-and-buried-503672.shtml) (I am sad too) there is a repackaged version which works on 16.04 announced in [this article](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-ubuntu-tweak-in-ubuntu-16-04/).

There is a ppa here

```
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps
```

for which the key is

```
wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Or you can just download the .deb from here

```
http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/apps/u/ubuntu-tweak/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1~getdeb2~xenial_all.deb
```

Comment: I'm getting `deb: command not found`. What's up with that?

Comment: That line is not a command, it goes in your /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I couldn't get it installed adding getdeb's repository. Does it really work? I needed to [do these](http://askubuntu.com/a/819056/61218)

Comment: It worked for me. What errors did you get?

Comment: @OrganicMarble the dependency error of gir1.2-vte-1.90

Comment: Try downloading the .deb

Answer (score 5):

**Quick answer:**

The program you're trying to install is abandonware (has been abondon and is no longer supported)... it isn't available for the latest Ubuntu (16.04).  You would have to use one of the other tweak programs available for the later versions of Ubuntu such as:

[gnome-tweak-tool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-tweak&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all)
or
[unity-tweak-tool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=unity-tweak&searchon=names)

**Detailed Resolution**

Alternatively ubuntu-tweak-tool has been repackaged of which you can find detailed installation instructions here:
[How can I install Ubuntu tweak on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770947/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-tweak-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Another alternative of this `gir1.2-vte-2.90`error been reported to [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+bug/1555706), where one of the users has described a method and provided files to make it run on Ubuntu 16.04.  Hist direct entry in the bug report is: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/+bug/1555706/comments/5

He has included a video report of how to use his resolution.

Comment: It is still available from getdeb.net for 16.04.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As L. D. James has already answered that Ubuntu tweak is discontinued and you better use other alternatives like **Unity Tweak tool** or **Gnome Tweak Tool**, but If you really want to use Ubuntu tweak on Xenial Xerus (16.04), here is the procedure. But, be warned that, many of the functionalities may not work properly.

### 1. Add GetDeb repository

I can see that you already downloaded Ubuntu Tweak's deb file. however, for others they need to add GetDeb's repository. Since this is the only repository still providing builds for Ubuntu Tweak (afaik).

Here is the procedure to add Getdeb's repository. http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/16.04#how_to_install

The easiest way is just downloading [getdeb package](http://archive.getdeb.net/install_deb/getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb) and installing it with

```
sudo dpkg -i getdeb-repository_0.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb
```

### 2. Create a package that provides `gir1.2-vte-2.90`

You can skip building of this proxy package by downloading my built one (If you trust of course). Here is the [dropbox link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35619242/gir1.2-vte-2.90-provider_1.0_all.deb) of that package .deb file. If you download .deb file, you can skip step 1, 2 and just install the package by following step 3.

- [gir1.2-vte-2.90-provider](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35619242/gir1.2-vte-2.90-provider_1.0_all.deb) deb file

#### Some Background:

Ubuntu 16.04 has the package `gir1.2-vte-2.91`. If you don't have it already installed, install it with

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-vte-2.91
```

Now, This package is a higher versioned of `gir1.2-vte-2.90` upon which Ubuntu Tweak depends. But since the version number is included in the package name, `apt` is failing to treat `gir1.2-vte-2.91` as a higher version of `gir1.2-vte-2.91`. But a package `gir1.2-vte-2.91` should really work in place of it.

So, our idea is, we will create a package that will provide `gir1.2-vte-2.90`, because we know, What Ubuntu Tweak needs is already in our system via `gir1.2-vte-2.91`.

#### Let's start.

1. First install `equivs`

   ```
   sudo apt install equivs
   ```
2. Then create a control file for our provider package `gir1.2-vte-2.90-provider`

   ```
   equivs-control gir1.2-vte-2.90
   ```
3. Step 2 will create a file named `gir1.2-vte-2.90`. Open it and replace it's content with these lines

   ```
   Section: misc
   Priority: optional
   Standards-Version: 3.9.2
   Package: gir1.2-vte-2.90-provider
   Version: 1.0
   Depends: gir1.2-vte-2.91
   Provides: gir1.2-vte-2.90
   Description: A proxy provider for gir1.2-vte-2.90 package
    A proxy provider for gir1.2-vte-2.90 package
   ```
4. Now use this command to generate the package

   ```
   equivs-build gir1.2-vte-2.90
   ```
5. Install newly generate package with `dpkg`

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i gir1.2-vte-2.90-provider_1.0_all.deb
   ```

### 3. Install Ubuntu Tweak

1. Now go to GetDeb's Ubuntu tweak page http://www.getdeb.net/software/ubuntu-tweak
2. Click on **Install this now** button.
3. A dialog will popup requesting permission to install package. Allow it.

Ubuntu tweak should be installed on your Xenial!

Comment: quite a work! +1, Have you tested it? Is it fully functional?

Comment: @souravc Of course I've tested it and I'm using Ubuntu Tweak in 16.04. As per functionality, most of them works except the Apps Tab.

Comment: In 16.04 Software center is replaced by  GNOME Software app. That may be the reason why apps tab is not working. I will give a try. Thanks.

Comment: It is still available from getdeb.net for 16.04.  See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. To download and install Ubuntu-Tweak for Ubuntu 16.04 do the following:

- Highlight, right click, and copy the code below:

  ```
  wget http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/apps/u/ubuntu-tweak/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1~getdeb2~xenial_all.deb
  ```
- Open your terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> at the same time or right click into a folder and left click <kbd>open in terminal</kbd>
- Paste the code into your terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> or right click into the terminal and the click <kbd>paste</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
- Double-click the file `ubuntu-tweak_0.8.7-1~getdeb2~xenial_all.deb` in the folder.

Software Center opens up, click <kbd>install</kbd>, type in your password when asked and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Finished!

Answer (score 1):

Good day! I noticed, that some links don't work on this post now and I found one site, where you can exactly find the necessary program:

- Go on https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-tweak/+packages. You must chose third paragraph under "Packages" (or someone else, if you have other distribution) and download any file, for example I downloaded "ubuntu-tweak_0.8.8-5~xenial_all.deb".
- Or you can iust click on https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-tweak/+files/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.8-5~xenial_all.deb, but in my opinion this link will not be working in the future.

I hope this information will be useful for comunity!

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak has been deprecated. This is very unfortunate, I really liked it enough to fix it after it had been discontinued. You can still install it, but you would go through a bunch of installing more deprecated software to do it.                                                                                         dep·re·cate
/ˈdeprəˌkāt/
Learn to pronounce
verb
past tense: deprecated; past participle: deprecated

    1.
    express disapproval of.