# Error every time I try to install some package with "app repository..."

Tags: apt, ppa

When I type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install "NAME OF THE PROGRAM"
```

there isn't any problem, but when I do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:"SMTHG HERE"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install "NAME OF THE PROGRAM"
```

I get the output:

```
E:Unable to locate package "NAME OF THE PROGRAM"
```

This has happened every time I try to install an application from a ppa.

Output of uname -a:
Linux dcalderon-MS-7693 3.19.0-73-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 18 16:03:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Specific example:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Perhaps giving a specific example of a PPA software package that isn't installing would help us help you. Please include the exact terminal commands you've tried, in order.

Comment: THis is a case where we need specifics. If everything's a variable, how are we supposed to know if you didn't simply add the wrong PPA?

Comment: Probably the package is not compiled for your Ubuntu release... but without example of PPA and information about your ubuntu version we can only guess.. .

Comment: Also add the output of `uname -a` to your question.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release? You can find out with the output of `lsb_release -a`. I suspect that you're running an outdated Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages that are in the [`ppa:tualatrix/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) are compiled for many Ubuntu versions up to 14.04. Trusty. Probably you are running 16.04 or 16.10 and that is the reason you cannot install the *ubuntu-tweak*. It is not an error and probably you fail installing other packages based on outdated Ubuntu tutorials that are misleading you (and many other users as well)...

There is a good explanation about manual install or alternative tweaks at [How can I install Ubuntu tweak on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/770947/325029)

Comment: With due respect, 16.06 doesn't exist. Perhaps you meant to say 16.10 (`yakkety`)? Please [edit] your answer.

Comment: Already done, 10x:).

Comment: OP has kernel v3.19 while Xenial and Yakkety have (at least) v4.4 and v4.8 respectively. It's more likely that OP is still on Vivid which leads to the same fundamental issue.