# Unable to locate package ubuntu-tweak

Tags: ubuntu-tweak

I tried to install ubuntu-tweak. I followed these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

But I got **Unable to locate package ubuntu-tweak**.

what else should I do to install ubuntu-tweak?

thanks much,
bfz

Comment: You will have to remove the repository you installed `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tualatrix-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` then check this answer for Ubuntu Tweak.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/770947/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-tweak-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: If you just want the janitor functionality, a fork of that part is still under active development. https://launchpad.net/~gerardpuig/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @Terrance how did you determine that BenZ was using Xenial? I've read through the question a few times, and I don't see that information anywhere.

Comment: @blendenzo It may not be Xenial, but that ppa stopped being supported since 14.04, so OP is using something newer than 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix

it seems there is also a 'next' PPA,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next
```

I have used the old version, but not this next version. But it seems no longer active, and I find no version for xenial and yakkety. *So you should stay away from it, at least not install it into your main operating system.*

**Edit:** I notice the comment by Terrance. It looks like the way to go :-)

[How can I install Ubuntu tweak on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770947/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-tweak-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Please try this 
    sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool