# I cant install ubuntu tweak on ubuntu 17.04 can anybody help me?

Tags: 17.04, tweak

Every time i wanted to install ubuntu tweak on ubuntu 17.04, "Unable to locate package ubuntu-tweak" What should i do????

Comment: Do you mean the Unity tweak tool?

Comment: Ubuntu tweak is no longer maintained since may 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Tweak is dead, Jim. It is no longer maintained.

The often-used cruft cleaning functions have been forked into Ubuntu Cleaner. There is a ppa (ppa:gerardpuig/ppa) or you can download it from [here](https://launchpad.net/~gerardpuig/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages).

Reference: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/12/free-space-ubuntu-cleaner-janitor-app

The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770947/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-tweak-on-ubuntu-16-04) talks about a repackaged version of the full app for 16.04.  I do not know if it is available for 17.04

Comment: For those who don't get the "dead, Jim" reference, I leave you with this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8QAbm687wU