# Separate wallpaper for login screen and desktop? (16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, login-screen, customization, desktop-background

I've tried searching for an answer to this with no luck.

I had a go at the method detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313526/changing-login-screen-wallpaper) but as soon as I log out the new wallpaper is there for a brief second before it changes back to my desktop wallpaper.

I feel silly asking a question like this as it must be simple but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've written a script for that before . Try it out: https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/chgreeterbg.sh

Comment: Some explanation of how that script works has been posted  on another question ( which is actually a duplicate of your question ) : http://askubuntu.com/a/694370/295286    Let me know if that helps

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate! I can confirm it worked perfectly. Many thanks for writing the script and also for sharing it with me :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)