# How to show user logo at login screen?

Tags: 16.04

How can I make Ubuntu 16.04 show my user logo/picture at the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Simple way, you can change the login background using Nautilus:

open Nautilus (in root mode)

go to /usr/share/backgrounds.

cut/move/delete "warty-final-ubuntu.png"

then choose the picture you want ( .png format)

rename it to "warty-final-ubuntu.png"

then move it back to /usr/share/backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what picture exactly you want to change.

1. You can change the background of your login screen. For that I would recommend you to choose lightdm as the login screen. There are plenty inctructions how to do that. Here are some [Changing login screen wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313526/changing-login-screen-wallpaper).
2. Another option is to show the picture of users that have accounts on your computer. In that case each user has to put a file with name `.face` in her home directory. A simpler way to do that is by selecting a picture for the user in User settings (https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/user-changepicture.html). There is a catch with this user picture. If a user has encrypted her home directory, the login application cannot read the encrypted picture and it will not show even if it was set correctly by the user.