# Changing login background automatically

Tags: login-screen, desktop-background

If I changed my desktop background picture, that picture would also be set to login screen. Now it's not working. Whatever I change, login background is the same picture (Ubuntu's default picture) How can I make it work?

Comment: Since Ubuntu 18.04 this is a solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1071765/34298

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered multiple times, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313526/changing-login-screen-wallpaper) is an appropriate link.

On your behalf I have tried all answers in this thread on Ubuntu 16.10 and I have only had success with one. Unfortunately it's the ugly one.

Firstly, make sure the picture you want to use is in .png format, then open your terminal:

```
cd /usr/share/backgrounds
sudo cp /directory/path/to/my/picture /usr/share/backgrounds
sudo mv warty-final-ubuntu.png warty-final-ubuntu2.png
sudo mv 'my-picture-name.png' warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

Then log out to see your new login wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a cronjob `/etc/cron.d/variety-background-cp` that copies the current background image every 10 minutes to a location outside of your encrypted home folder:

   ```
   # hourly copy background image
   */10 * * * * your-sername cp "$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri|sed "s~'file://\(.*\)'~\1~")" /usr/share/backgrounds/current-background.png
   ```
2. Backup the ubuntu theme file with

   ```
   cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css /var/tmp/
   ```
3. edit the `#lockDialogGroup` section in your `ubuntu.css`, for example

   ```
   #lockDialogGroup {
      background: #2c001e url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/current-background.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
   }
   ```
4. **reboot**

see https://askubuntu.com/a/1145846/34298