# Login screen image not showing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login-screen

After installing ubuntu 18.04 I have now a noisy background when being on the login screen, there is not a nice image anymore and the login experience feels a little screwed up (tap on touchpad doesn't work either for example).

It could be worth mentioning that I have installed **/ root** on a 25gb SSD to have a faster file transfer/boot up time and installed the **/home** in the HDD.

Any Ideas of what could be happening?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but to change your Login screen image read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042942/how-to-change-ubuntu-budgie-login-screen-background and this: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/10/change-login-screen-background-ubuntu-17-10/

Comment: the weird part is that I never even saw the original image showing in the login screen for ubuntu, I tried the recommendation on the first link you shared but it's not working :c

Comment: I up-voted your question. Hopefully it attracts attention of other users who have seen the problem.

Comment: @Enmanual Duran after installing Ubuntu 18.04 have you successfully logged on to your session? Can you attach picture of what you see at login screen? By default login screen is Ubuntu's Purple Color..