# Settings schema 'x.dm.slick-greeter' is not installed

Tags: 18.04, lightdm

I wanted to have a login screen background on Ubuntu 18.04. I followed this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1043034/167612 but it wasn't of much success. Any kind of clue will be helpful.

```
user:~$ sudo lightdm-settings

(lightdm-settings:6696): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 14:23:27.908: Settings schema 'x.dm.slick-greeter' is not installed

user:~$
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt install slick-greeter`.

Comment: @Jos Thanks man. It is working fine. Please put that in the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`lightdm-settings` needs `slick-greeter` (https://github.com/linuxmint/slick-greeter) to be installed, even though it is not listed as a dependency. So just do

```
sudo apt install slick-greeter
```