# Log-in screen background (on Ubuntu 18.04) is not changing though I made necessary changes in necessary files

Tags: login-screen

Actually the instructions for changing the log-in screen background are very clear and distinct. So, I don't think I made anything wrong. First I copied my desired image here `/usr/share/backgrounds/drawing.png`.
I opened this ( `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` ) as a super user and I replaced

```
#lockDialogGroup {
background: #2c001e url(file:///org/something_path);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

with this

```
#lockDialogGroup {
background: #2c001e url(file:///usr/share/backgrounds/drawing.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
```

and saved successfully. Then I rebooted but the background is not changed. But when I put anyother color code instead of `#2c001e` the color gets changed. Please help me to understand what and why is wrong with the changing of background image?

Comment: can you share the file drawing.png

Comment: sure, here it is https://ibb.co/8m20C7k

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/uXn9Ato

Comment: Hi, it worked for me..  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hocd1.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgCHj.png Did you change any other things that you remember?

Comment: I think I might have done something while customizing the shell. Is there anything I can do to reset this log in and shell theme settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you followed has worked for most people:

- [How to change Ubuntu Budgie login screen background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042942/how-to-change-ubuntu-budgie-login-screen-background/1071765#1071765)

However it didn't work for everyone and there is a lesser known technique in the same thread where they simply copy over the pre-packaged image filename with a new image:

> I tried all of those and none worked. This does, for sure:
>
> As root user, just copy your_image.png to /usr/share/backgrounds and
>   ....
>
> ```
> # cd /usr/share/backgrounds
> # cp warty-final-ubuntu.png warty-final-ubuntu.png.stock
> # rm warty-final-ubuntu.png
> # ln -s your_image.png warty-final-ubuntu.png
> # reboot
> ```
>
> ...where your_image.png is the name of the actual image you want to
>   display. The warty one is big: 4096 x 2304. I matched mine to the same
>   size.