# How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: themes, login-screen, gdm, 20.04, css

How can I change the Ubuntu 20.04 login screen theme or background?

In the previous version 19.10, I can change it from the CSS file under Yaru theme but now there is no CSS file.

Comment: The answer is to install vanilla-gnome-default-settings. This will set the GDM theme to Gnome stock, and also give you the option of continuing to use Yaru as your theme or the stock stock Gnome theme.

Comment: I haven't tested this on 20.04, but I believe my answer here for how to do this on 21.10 should work on 20.04, and it doesn't require installing any third-party scripts or extracting gresource files: https://askubuntu.com/a/1396066/84581

Answer (score 35):

In previous versions of Ubuntu since its introduction of gdm3 for login greeter, the style sheet file is directly available to edit.

for example:

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css #for Ubuntu 18.04
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css` #for Ubuntu 19.10
```

are the files being used as alternatives.

The name of alternatives is `gdm3.css`.

for *Ubuntu 20.04* the equivalent to above is `gdm3-theme.gresource`

```
$ update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource   
There are 3 choices for the alternative gdm3-theme.gresource (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm3-theme.gresource).

  Selection    Path                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        auto mode
  1            /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/theme/focalgdm3.gresource          0         manual mode
  2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource              10        manual mode
  3            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

from the core files of Ubuntu, the config for gdm is

```
stylesheetName: 'gdm3.css',
themeResourceName: 'gdm3-theme.gresource',
```

the above means that one needs to edit the file `gdm3.css` inside the `.gresource` file from the above `update-alternatives` result. Or install some other `.gresource` files which have the compatibility for Ubuntu 20.04.
for example in above output you have the choice of

```
.../gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

as an alternative. If you trust some other (external sources) `.gresource` files that have the compatibility for Ubuntu 20.04,
You can install them as an alternative and use it.

If you want to edit,

for example, you can extract the `gdm3.css` and see the color that is configured for login screen background.

run the below commands one by one

```
gresource extract /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource /org/gnome/shell/theme/gdm3.css > $HOME/gdm3.css
gedit $HOME/gdm3.css
```

some of the content:

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background-color: #4f194c; }
```

Editing this content with your required content and recompiling it to create new `.gresource` file is required. After which you can install this new `.gresource` file as an alternative and select it.

How to extract and compile?

***Disclimer: this  [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310923/how-to-customize-gnome-login-screen-in-debian)  is only for Idea. Proper making and configuration is required for getting things to work for Ubuntu 20.04 Otherwise system will be bricked.*** Please note that this post is quite older and contents vary from Ubuntu 20.04.

Also note that the package `libglib2.0-dev` is required to compile the `.gresource` file.

---

Well, seems the process is very heavy just for changing the login screen background, rite? what if you want to change the background Image or color of the Login screen frequently?

***[Workaround](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/ubuntu-gdm-set-background)*** 
for changing login background with Image/ Color/ Gradient Horizontal/Vertical with a script.

you can download the `ubuntu-gdm-set-background` file via command line

```
wget -qO - https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/ubuntu-gdm-set-background/archive/main.tar.gz | tar zx --strip-components=1 ubuntu-gdm-set-background-main/ubuntu-gdm-set-background
```

Once you downloaded the script `ubuntu-gdm-set-background`.

Make sure you have installed the required package, `libglib2.0-dev-bin`.
If not installed, Install it with the command

```
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev-bin
```

there are four options

background with image
background with color
background with gradient horizontal ( requires two valid hex color inputs)
background with gradient vertical ( requires two valid hex color inputs)

tip: be ready with valid hex color code in place of below example like `#aAbBcC` or `#dDeEfF`. Change them to your preferred hex color codes. you may choose colors from https://www.color-hex.com/

Example Commands:

```
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --image /home/user/backgrounds/image.jpg
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --color \#aAbBcC
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --gradient horizontal \#aAbBcC \#dDeEfF
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --gradient vertical \#aAbBcC \#dDeEfF
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --reset
./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --help
```

try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go the gdm screen to see the change.

If change does not appear, then restart gdm with below command

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will you be able to help with this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233580/ubuntu-on-wayland-theme-and-appearance-set-to-ubuntu-20-04-default-session-ho ?
The 20.04 default log out/ power off screen had a cool blur effect with some nice icon and effects. I lost that and instead getting a dialog box. Any idea, how to restore that and choose the right setting to bring it back?

Comment: I tried Workaround 2 and specified background image path as /home/username/Pictures/mybackground.jpg but it did not appear on the login screen. On the other hand, when I saved the same image as /usr/share/backgrounds/mybackground.jpg then it was displayed as the background.

Comment: Yes, /home/username is the path of my home directory. The problem is actually caused by the permissions of that directory: rwxrwx--- (770). The process that displays the login screen background probably runs as gdm user and so it cannot access the picture inside my home directory.

Comment: Nice catch.....

Comment: Thanks a lot. Workaround 2 worked.

Answer (score 12):

Easy! Just download the script from https://github.com/thiggy01/ubuntu-20.04-change-gdm-background, chmod +x the script, run like this:

First, install this package:

```
sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev-bin
```

Now, run the script:

```
sudo ./Scriptname picturename
```

To restore default background:

```
sudo ./Scriptname --restore
```

This only works on 20.04.

Comment: when I tried to download the script from the link with the below command:
curl -L -O github.com/thiggy01/ubuntu-20.04-change-gdm-background/raw/master/ubuntu-20.04-change-gdm-background
I'm getting permission denied error!

Comment: Thanks for the post. The script already asks if you want to install libglib2.0-dev-bin. @SubinR try with `wget github.com/thiggy01/ubuntu-20.04-change-gdm-background/raw/master/ubuntu-20.04-change-gdm-background`.

Comment: this is easiest foolproof solution for Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/juhaku/loginized which is an `elegant software` to update GDM3 theme for Ubuntu 20.04. With this you can change `gtk-theme`, `login screen background` and `screen shield wallpaper`.

If you also want to change `cursor-theme` and `icon-theme` you can use `gdm3setup`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

On **Ubuntu 22.04**, this didn't work for me. The script kept giving me an error message.
The solution that ended up being successful for me was simply using a few commands to login as GDM user and set the path to the image, as follows :

```
sudo machinectl shell gdm@ /bin/bash
```

Then

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.login-screen background-picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'
```

And finally logging out using

```
exit
```

This procedure is from a bug description which can be found at [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1929536).

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a brand new Framework 13 laptop. Processor is an AMD Ryzen 7784u.
I post this here because I came across this page while looking for a way to change the login background to an image. So I guess it might help other people too :) .