# Change font size of top bar in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, top-bar

Has somebody tried change the font size of top bar in Ubuntu 20.04? It looks like approach to modifying has been changed compare to Ubuntu 18.04. I've done recommendations from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-to-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-20-04). I've changed `font-size` in `stage` section, but looks like this is applied only to logon screen.

```
/* Global Values */
stage {
  font-size: 9pt;
  color: #3D3D3D; }
```

So, it looks correct on logon screen:

[image: logon]

But nothing change in user session:

[image: session]

If somebody has ideas how to change font size of top bar in Ubuntu 20.04, then please share.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In fact, I've tried to add ```font-size``` to file ```~/.themes/Yaru/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css```, but without success. Appearance of top bar is not changed.

Comment: @PRATAP, no, all is by default, expect changes that were done according to your suggestions in https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focal_gdm3_complete_hack. in fact, I've changed only ```font-size``` in ```stage``` section of gdm3.css file.
In Ubuntu 18.04 it was enough to change font size of top bar in logon screen and desktop.

Comment: I'd like to use default theme, just change font size of top bar. There is no ```/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css``` file in case of using default theme, only gnome-shell-theme.gresource.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you have idea how font size of top bar can be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

follow this post to bring the default yaru shell theme to local
https://askubuntu.com/a/1231311/739431

and then edit the required content as you wish like below;

```
/* Top Bar */
#panel {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 1.86em;
  font-feature-settings: "tnum";
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; /* added this line */
  font-size: 22px; } /* added this line */
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it crashed my computer. I had to boot to command prompt and put it back. :(

Comment: Most other font sizes are specified in points, so I used `15pt`.