# How to enable top bar background opacity?

Tags: 20.04

There is a way to change top bar background opacity in ubuntu 20.04 lts. 
I installed the hide top bar extension but is not a option to change it.

Comment: it is possible but lot of procedure.. it is per shell theme based.. what is the shell theme u r using/ going to use?

Comment: default shell theme

Comment: Ok.. for the default Shell theme you want to set the opacity. Rite.. I shall see a workaround for this in some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***WORKAROUND***

Using this post [Install Adwaita shell theme on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231043/install-adwaita-shell-theme-on-ubuntu-20-04) Extract the contents for the default theme `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file.

[image]

Then from the `Yaru` directory in the above pic, copy the `gnome-shell.css` file to
`$HOME/.local/share/themes/myYaru/gnome-shell` or `$HOME/.themes/myYaru/gnome-shell` directory. Create the Directory's as necessary.

> [ here in this file `gnome-shell.css`, there are some paths which specify `resource` you
>   should play tricks if theme is not effective with those paths ]
>
> [In my trail It was not needed. But you have to play tricks with the
>   folders and paths if something is not showing properly.]

Example:

```
  background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-off.svg"); }
  background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-off-focused.svg"); }
  background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox.svg"); }
  background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/checkbox-focused.svg"); }
  background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-off.svg"); }
  background-image: url("resource:///org/gnome/shell/theme/toggle-on.svg"); }
```

to use this shell theme `myYaru` you need to install User Shell theme gnome-shell extension.

then select it from `gnome-tweaks`

[image]

now you have the local copy of the default shell theme. so you can edit `gnome-shell.css` file in this local theme.

now open the file `$HOME/.local/share/themes/myYaru/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`

and go to line number around 1141;

```
/* Top Bar */
#panel {
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
```

change this with rgba color to control the opacity.

example:

```
/* Top Bar */
#panel {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

save the file and refresh the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 'r' Enter method.

[image]

with opacity set to 0.05 i.e rgba(0,0,0,0.05)

[image]

Comment: I need to do this manual patching on every update of the theme, right?

Comment: no no need.. alternatives are there..