# How do I resize app icons in applications overview on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, 20.04

I installed **Ubuntu 20.04** *Focal Fossa* yesterday. I think it's great so far and was able to customize a lot with the tools *Tweaks* and *dconf Editor*. However, unfortunately I have not yet managed to to reduce the size of GNOME Shell's *dash* icons.

There is an [Ask Ubuntu solution for Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1049325/1067785) which doesn't seem to work anymore for *Focal Fossa* as the files mentioned in the answer no longer exist. Instead, there's now only a single `.gresource` file.

Is there another better/new way to adjust the icon size?

Comment: if we're talking about the favorites icons in Ubuntu dash to dock, it's possible to change via GUI in settings>appearence. Or do oyu mean anything else?

Comment: @ivan No, OP meant the ones in the applications overview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg1Lz.jpg "Dash" in not the proper and unambiguous term here.

Comment: seems like .css file has been replaced with .gresource file if I'm not wrong. There was a script to replace logon screen for GDM and prior to 20.0 it refered to .css one, now as I can see it refers to .gresource: https://github.com/thiggy01/ubuntu-20.04-change-gdm-background/blob/master/ubuntu-20.04-change-gdm-background. dash settings must be there too, there's a /* Dash */ section in this file, not sure if it similar to the previous manual since I do not have 18.0 anymore but it worth checking

Comment: @pomsky In `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/`there's only a `gnome-shell.gresource`file. I figured out that I can view its content via `gresource list` command. Included is in fact a `gnome-shell.css`. So if I would unpack it, I could certainly change it. But how I should use the modified file is unclear to me.

Comment: @FIKo is your aim to reduce the size of the icons?? just in case  if you are thinking it will increase the number of coloumns, its not. It will only change the size of icons and looks ugly.. If you are satisfied with the Question you linked in your Question... you can achieve that by understanding this Q&A concept.. https://askubuntu.com/a/1231311/739431

Comment: @PRATAP Yes, I'd been hoping to change the size **and** the column/row count. Thank you for pointing that out and also for the link. I'll follow the described steps and see if I can get any further with it.

Comment: there is a extension for it.. i think thats in the question you linked...

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/