# 'Ubuntu on Wayland' theme and appearance set to Ubuntu 20.04 default Session. How to restore back?

Tags: icons, themes, wayland

I chose the 'Ubuntu on Wayland' session from the settings like icon from the right corner of the login screen and logged in.

Once I logged out and logged back in the Ubuntu default session, the theme and icon appearance got set from the Wayland session.

How can I restore the default theme and appearance of the Ubuntu 20.04 back ?

I lost the new features of 20.04 like the Ubuntu boot screen with Dell logo.
And the power off/log out blur effect screen instead getting Wayland's dialog box. Not sure how to get that back.
Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I tried it.. Sorry its working same as default `Ubuntu` session. I cant reproduce the issue..

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have installed KDE also, on top of it. Maybe that is causing the issue. Thanks anyway!