# How to customize Lock Screen theme in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, 20.04, login-screen, lock-screen

I changed the gnome shell theme of the login screen to Yaru-dark by following instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-do-i-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-ubuntu-20-04). I did notice the dark calendar and system menu when I *log on after reboot*. However, when I lock my computer with Super+L, the *lock screen* still has white calendar and system menu, so I would like to make those dark as well.

All the answers I've seen so far are for Ubuntu 18.04, since they refer to `/usr/share/gnome-shell/ubuntu.css` which I do not have. I *do* have a `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`, but changing that to my dark theme gresource still results in light shell on lock screen. Some other answers refer to a `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gdm3.css`, which I do not have either (the only css file I see in that directory is a `gnome-classic.css`).

I would just like to know which css file or which gresource file controls the lock screen theme on Ubuntu 20.04.

[image: A screenshot of my white system menu from the lock screen]

Comment: Hi yaru dark on login screen how did you do that workaround 1 from the answer or someother way?

Comment: @PRATAP I did not use your workaround 1. I extracted and modified the original `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`, then packed it into my own gresource file. I then made a new directory `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru-dark` and placed my modified gresource file in it. Lastly, I used `sudo update-alternatives` to change the link `gdm3-theme.gresource` to point to the modified gresource file. The result was that the gnome shell on the login reboot screen became dark, which is great, but the lock screen remained unchanged.

Comment: 0k thanks for clarification.. it is possible also for lock screen.. i am working on it.. Will let u know in some time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04,
the default shell theme.. and lock screen both are configured to use the css file

`Yaru/gnome-shell.css` which is inside the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`

this is configured in the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "Yaru/gnome-shell.css",
    "themeResourceName": "theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource",
    "debugFlags": ["backtrace-crashes-all"],
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com", "desktop-icons@csoriano"]
}
```

So, you can pointout what ever `.gresource` file you want to use and the corresponding `gnome-shell.css`

for example, If I want Yaru-dark theme, I can simply point out like this by editing the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`

**Take Backup of the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json` before editing**

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "Yaru-dark/gnome-shell.css",
    "themeResourceName": "theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource",
    "debugFlags": ["backtrace-crashes-all"],
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com", "desktop-icons@csoriano"]
}
```

[image]

Please note that Default shell theme and lock screen uses same file.. so If you want Yaru shell theme for the desktop session.. you need to install it as a local theme which is another topic.

I have not tried with full path of the `.gresource` file.. in the line

```
"themeResourceName": "theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource",
```

this means.. `theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` is a relative path of the base `/usr/share/gnome-shell`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. So basically themeResourceName is the relative path to the gresource file and stylesheetName is the path within the gresource file, correct?

Comment: Note: Do *not* save a backup of any `*.json` file in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/` using an extension *appended* to the end of the original full-filename. For example, do not save `ubuntu.json` as `ubuntu.json.backup`. Ubuntu will frustratingly load your backup as if it were a valid file. Instead, drop the `json` part of the back up filename, and you will not have this issue. For example, it is OK to save a copy of your original `ubuntu.json` file as `ubuntu.backup`, and your *new* `ubuntu.json` file will be loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

How to Change Lock Screen Background Wallpaper in Ubuntu 20.04
Leave a comment, please.

> 1.) Open terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard. When it opens, run command to make sure gir1.2-clutter-1.0 library is installed:

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

> 2.) Then in web browser go to extensions.gnome.org/extension/1476/unlock-dialog-background/.

Click on the toggle and confirm on the next pop-up to install the extension.

Don’t see the toggle? Do following steps, then refresh the web page.

Click the link text “click here to install browser extension” and follow the pop-ups to install the browser extension:
shell browser extension
Then open terminal and run command:

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

3.) Launch either Extensions utility or Gnome Tweaks > Extensions (install it via Ubuntu Software), go to the extension settings page, and finally set a picture for lock screen background.

That’s All. Enjoy!
I hope you find this helpful.