# Lock screen shell not in dark mode / specific theme

Tags: command-line, gnome, 20.04, themes

I notice that my shell on my lock screen wasn't the same theme was when I'm logged into my user.
I was wondering if that is changeable into a dark mode or even a specific shell theme that I have downloaded.

Things I've tried to change to dark mode:

Edit the stylesheet in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`
from

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "Yaru/gnome-shell.css",
    "themeResourceName": "theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource",
    "debugFlags": ["backtrace-crashes-all"],
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com", "desktop-icons@csoriano"]
}
```

to

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "Yaru-dark/gnome-shell.css",
    "themeResourceName": "theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource",
    "debugFlags": ["backtrace-crashes-all"],
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com", "desktop-icons@csoriano"]
}
```

However, this didn't work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: same thing worked for me when I tested for this post.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1238438/739431

Comment: @PRATAP I tried that one out but it didn't have any effect...

Comment: have you configured anything on default Ubuntu 20.04 Installation?