# change GNOME 3.36 gdm3 lock screen (screen shield) font colour - what css selector to target in gdm3.css?

Tags: gnome, themes, fonts, lock-screen, gdm

I am aware from other posts that you can change e.g. the login screen background by modifying the css selector `#lockDialogGroup` in `gdm3.css` that you get when extracting the `.gresource` binary.

What is the equivalent for changing the clock / time font in the lock screen (screen shield)? I tried changing `.unlock-dialog-clock` and `.unlock-dialog-clock-time` but to not much result. Am I targetting the right selectors?

EDIT after discussion:

My workflow is as follows:

extract / edit / compile in `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/theme/Pop-modified`, which is under [version control](https://github.com/zegheim/Pop-modified/) (see below):

[image: dedicated folder for editing files; trac]

To apply the changes, I run the following command:

`sudo cp ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/theme/Pop-modified/gnome-shell-theme.gresource /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Pop-modified/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`

which is where `gdm3-theme.gresource` is pointing to, using `update-alternatives` (see below):

```
➜ update-alternatives --config gdm3-theme.gresource
There are 3 choices for the alternative gdm3-theme.gresource (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm3-theme.gresource).

  Selection    Path                                                                   Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Pop/gnome-shell-theme.gresource            20        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource                      10        manual mode
* 2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Pop-modified/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   0         manual mode
  3            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Pop/gnome-shell-theme.gresource            20        manual mode
```

The actual edits are done as follows:

- Rename `gdm3.css` and `gnome-shell.css` to `gdm3-original.css` and `gnome-shell-original.css` respectively.
- Create new files called [`gdm3.css`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zegheim/Pop-modified/master/theme/gdm3.css) and [`gnome-shell.css`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zegheim/Pop-modified/master/theme/gnome-shell.css), import the original css files and make all desired changes to these files.

Currently, the edits I made under `#lockDialogGroup` is in effect but not those under `.unlock-dialog-clock`.

GNOME shell version:

```
➜ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.36.3
```

Contents of `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes`:

```
➜ ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/modes
initial-setup.json  pop.json  ubuntu.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, concentrate on the text "green" in the below content..

```
/* Screen Shield */
.unlock-dialog-clock {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  spacing: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 2.5em; }
```

[image: screenshot with green text]

In your case, the `.gresource` file you have edited is not used by the lock screen..

For the lock screen, which .gresource or css file is used, varies from your OS rather than simply `gnome 3.36`

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238670/739431) for further information.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110736/discussion-on-answer-by-pratap-change-gnome-3-36-gdm3-lock-screen-screen-shield).