# Ubuntu 20.04 Login with no "see password" option

Tags: password, login-screen

is there a way to disable the eye icon in the login screen to prevent from someone "accidentally" turning it on and thus showing their password in plain sight? Thank you!

Comment: The problem with that is that every time I upgrade Ubuntu I will have to modify it and recompile it again. Not very practical.

Comment: It is perfectly OK if all of that goes away

Comment: It's OK just avoiding the "eye" icon.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Somehow the regular loading screen got screwed (now it says "MATE"), but I don't care, the eye disappeared. Thank you very much!

Comment: It worked in the login screen, however, in the lock screen it's still there :(

Comment: Yes, sure, there's no hurry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, The workaround is to set the eye-icon size to 1px so that it is not visible and not reactive..

***To use the workaround***

Download the script from github with below command..

```
wget -qO - https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3/archive/remove-eye-icon.tar.gz | tar zx --strip-components=1 focalgdm3-remove-eye-icon/focalgdm3
```

Run the command

```
sudo ./focalgdm3 \#4f194c
```

Optionally you may change the color `#4f194c` in above command with any color or you may replace the color `\#4f194c` with an absolute path of the Image if you wish an Image as background.

[image]

For reverting back to normal

Run the command

```
sudo ./focalgdm3 --reset
```

The above works only for login screen.. and not for lock screen, to use the same theme file for lock screen, we need to configure it separately.

---

***Configuring the same file for lockscreen***

copy the gresource file used for login screen with below command to system default folder

```
sudo cp /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/theme/custom/custom-gnome-shell-theme.gresource /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/
```

[image]

```
$ ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/
custom-gnome-shell-theme.gresource  gnome-shell-theme.gresource
$
```

Now to get away the changes we are doing from system upgrades.. make a local copy of the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json`

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/modes
cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/modes
```

Open the file `ubuntu.json`

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json
```

Now edit the `ubuntu.json` file to use our login screen `gdm3.css` file with below content..

```
{
    "parentMode": "user",
    "stylesheetName": "gdm3.css",
    "themeResourceName": "theme/Yaru/custom-gnome-shell-theme.gresource",
    "debugFlags": ["backtrace-crashes-all"],
    "enabledExtensions": ["ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com", "ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com", "desktop-icons@csoriano"]
}
```

Now reboot to see the changes..

[image]

To revert back to normal, remove the two files we created for lock screen purpose..

```
sudo rm /usr/local/share/gnome-shell/modes/ubuntu.json /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/custom-gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

References:
[How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227070/739431)
[How to customize Lock Screen theme in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1238438/739431)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It tackles the problem, though, it's a very weird workaround. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: Better way would be to compile the gnome-shell which may require programming language or atleast a grip on java scripts.. In that way programmer can remove the concept of eye icon.