# How to disable the Password Reveal button on the Sign-in screen on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, password

On Ubuntu  Canonical is adding a lot of significant changes to the operating system. For example, now the Sign-in screen there is a Password Reveal button. But I don't like it Can someone help me how i can  disable the Password Reveal button on the Sign-in screen on Ubuntu 20.04
Thanks[image]

Comment: Hi, there is a workaround for this but If you are new to OS you may break the OS..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1262188/739431