# Login Screen: Disable the password visibility toggling button

Tags: 20.04, security, login-screen, gdm, privacy

I have a default 20.04 Ubuntu install and the login screen has a password-visibility toggling button (an eye). I wish to disable this button and make the password always invisible. How can I do this? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: [This might give you what you need](https://askubuntu.com/a/1262645/1091774). It's not an easy fix, but it does seem possible 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 Login with no "see password" option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262188/ubuntu-20-04-login-with-no-see-password-option)

Comment: It does, but it is a shitty workaround. I wish there was a better answer