# GDM 3 - How to deactivate session choice?

Tags: gdm, session

When I enter my password in GDM 3, I can choose the session I want (Gnome, KDE, and whatever is installed).

I have set a default session and I would like my users not to be able to use another one than the default.

Please advise.

Comment: What is the output of `ls /usr/share/xsessions` and `dpkg -S /usr/share/xsessions` ?

Comment: a quickest way would be like similar to this https://askubuntu.com/q/1262188/739431. A programmatic way requires lot of work and that too at every update it vanishes.

Comment: to UnKNOWn, please read the question before sending a link.... Maybe i don't give enough specificities in my question though...