# 20.04 change Yaru purple into old green

Tags: 20.04, themes

I changed to Adwaita because the purple in Yaru was annoying. But I still get Purple here and there. Is there any method to change Yaru Purple in the core to the old green which was there initially ? I am ok with editing PNG and SVG if required.  Using the latest 20.04. Thanks.

Eg.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-do-i-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: No, I am trying to change the Purple inside the theme. ie, when I use Inkscape, certain elements like `seek bar ` appears in Purple. Thanks.