# How can I add a splash screen to gnome 3.36 Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, gdm

My gnome takes 30 seconds to load(I know this is rather long but it's a low end pc) and staring at a purple screen the whole time sometimes gets boring.

How can I add a custom splash that would show just before I get to the desktop?(time between the gdm screen and when gnome desktop is ready)

Comment: @UnKNOWn  .  Yes exactly that

Comment: GNOME 3.36.3     ,A background of my choice would be okay

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1227070/739431

Comment: i managed to change the gdm login background ,it does the trick