# How to customise GDM?

Tags: 20.04, gdm, customization

I found [this article](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-gdm-gnome-display-manager-theme-in-ubuntu.html), but there is no such setting in Ubuntu 20.04 am I right?

Comment: The article is dated `May 21, 2009`... Ubuntu has come a long way since then, as you say you are on 20.04.

Edit: does this answer your question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-do-i-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-ubuntu-20-04)?

Comment: Not quite. It helps me customise my background, but there is no solution to customise montior layout and image zoom. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Monitor layout can be changed through your Display options. If you type "Display" in Ubuntu's application search bar, it comes up as Screen Display or Displays or something related. You can customise image zoom (or resolution) and layout of monitors.