# How to Change Ubuntu 21.10 GDM background to a Image or to a Color

Tags: login-screen, gdm, 21.10

How to Change Ubuntu 21.10 gdm background  to a Image or to a Color.

Below Pic is of Ubuntu 20.04 GDM Login Screen
[image]

Is there a way similar to this post which is for Ubuntu 20.04 [How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227070/739431)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu [recently added](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1929536) the ability to customize this without relying on any third-party scripts (this is not yet possible if using GDM with a distro other than Ubuntu, see [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3877) for progress on that).

First install `systemd-container`:

```
sudo apt install systemd-container
```

Now we need to login as the `gdm` user before we run any `gsettings` commands:

```
sudo machinectl shell gdm@ /bin/bash
```

Now we can set the background to any image:

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.login-screen background-picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'
```

Other than `background-picture-uri`, you can also set `background-color` to just change the color without setting an image. If you set an image, you can also set the `background-repeat` and `background-size` settings.

(Note that you'll only see this image/color on the login screen, not the lock screen, which will instead be a blurred version of your desktop wallpaper)

Comment: how to reset?  ..

Answer (score 3):

For Changing the GDM Login Screen Background with a Image, Color or Gradient Horizontal or Vertical. There is a script in github. https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/ubuntu-gdm-set-background.

You can download the script with the below command

```
wget -qO - https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/ubuntu-gdm-set-background/archive/main.tar.gz | tar zx --strip-components=1 ubuntu-gdm-set-background-main/ubuntu-gdm-set-background
```

Once the script is downloaded, you can read the help with below command

```
./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --help
```

to set the background as image, run the below command. Replace the path of the image to your preferred one.

```
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --image /home/user/backgrounds/image.jpg
```

to set the background as color, run the below command. Replace the Hex Color Code with your preferred one.

```
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --color \#aAbBcC
```

to set the background as gradient's horizontal or vertical. Run the below command with either horizontal or vertical as choice and by replacing the two Hex color codes as you wish

```
sudo ./ubuntu-gdm-set-background --gradient horizontal \#aAbBcC \#dDeEfF
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

impishgdm:

- Examples do not work. Attempting to set an image or color complains that you didn't specify --set
- Using --set  does not work. Script still prompts for color or image later anyway
- Doesn't handle filepaths with spaces.

impish-gdm-set-background:

- Seems to work as advertised - at least for setting and image.
- Handles filepaths with spaces.

Why doesn't someone just combine all of these different gdm background checkers to sense the disto and do the right thing? In fact, it should be part of Ubuntu/GDM.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3 repository for use in Ubuntu 21.10.

https://github.com/dtalens/impishgdm

## impishgdm

***This script assumes that the Installation of Ubuntu 21.10 is a fresh install. If you tried to change the GDM background with someother scripts, you first need to reset those changes. Other scripts may have the option --reset.***

Change the login screen background for Ubuntu 21.10 only.

this script is to change the login screen background of Ubuntu 21.10 only.

you can download the `impishgdm` file via command line

```
wget -qO - https://github.com/dtalens/impishgdm/archive/TrailRun.tar.gz | tar zx --strip-components=1 impishgdm-TrailRun/impishgdm
```

Once you downloaded the script `focalgdm3`. cd to the downloaded script file.

to set the background with Image
`sudo ./impishgdm /absolute/path/to/image`

to set the background with color
`sudo ./impishgdm \#aAbBcC` replace `#aAbBcC` with any vaid hex color code..

to reset everything that the script made..
`sudo ./impishgdm --reset`