# How to change Ubuntu Logo on Login Screen?

Tags: gnome, login-screen, plymouth, desktop-background, logo

I changed the logo named **ubuntu-logo.png** under **/usr/share/plymouth**

But, it reverts to the original logo (please click/tap on the "Image" for reference) after I rebooted my system.

[GDM Background](https://github.com/thiggy01/change-gdm-background) is not compatible with my system, Ubuntu 22.04 either to resolve my issue.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46FsB.png)

Comment: could you write the output of `/usr/share/plymouth/plymouthd.defaults`? It may be using a theme

Comment: Do you mean /usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png? It's the default logo which we can see on the above link named "Image"

Comment: I hope updating grub helps

Comment: I'm not pertaining to GRUB2 but to the login screen logo where you can input your password to access the Desktop

Comment: my bad, I was explaining boot splash screen, hope this link helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-do-i-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: No worries, anyway, the link you provided is not applicable for 22.04 and I tried the other option already which is the GDM Background link above that doesn't work either. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: plymouth is only for boot screens, it will not affect the login screen. For that you need to make a custom GDM theme, probably. Or check out https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-logo.html.en not sure if it still is relevant for newer versions, but it may be