# How to change the Ubuntu login screen background in 22.10?

Tags: gnome, login

The login screen background is rather bland and I'd like to change it. I've tried using gnome-tweaks but to no avail. Alternatively, I also tried modifying the gdm3-theme.gresource file but was unable to make any progress.

How should I go on about modifying the login screen background? Should I build a modified gdm3 resource file and forces changes through it? Or is there a simpler way? (My knowledge about Ubuntu and linux systems in general is still at it's nascent stage...so pardon any newbie questions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change login screen theme or background in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227070/how-do-i-change-login-screen-theme-or-background-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Since the version of Gnome in Ubuntu 22.10 is GNOME 42 and not 3 like in Ubuntu 20.04 it is probably a different directory.