# How can I have my login screen use the same wallpaper as my desktop?

Tags: lightdm, desktop-background, pcmanfm

I use pcmanfm to display wallpapers on my desktop. The location of the conf file for pcmanfm is `~/.config/pcmanfm/lubuntu`. In this file the wallpaper is simply set in this form:

> wallpaper=/PATH/TO/IMAGE/FILE/image.jpg

How would I go about getting that information to the configuration file of the lightdm greeter? `/etc/xdg/lubuntu/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`

The background in the configuration file of the greeter is set like this:

> background=/PATH/TO/IMAGE/FILE/image.jpg

Is there any way that I could link it, or something else with the desired result?

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/142766/changing-wallpaper-on-12-04-login-screen/142771#142771

Comment: I'm afraid not, since I use pcmanfm for my desktop wallpaper. As noted above it will only change that one line in the pcmanfm.conf file. It will have no impact on the login screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LightDM use AccountsService to get user's wallpaper.

I do not use pcmanfm, but at first look it seems that pcmanfm do not interact with AccountsService to update information about wallpaper.

There are 2 options:

1. Wait for needed pcmanfm functionality (or just search for related bugs - maybe it's already reported but not implemented).
2. You can edit "/var/lib/AccountsService/users/$USER" file.
   Add following line to change your wallpaper at login screen for specified user:

   ```
   background=path/to/image
   ```

Comment: Yes, pcmanfm does not interact with AccountsService as far as I know. I must admit I'm not too familiar with the workings of AccountsService (much less lightdm's or pcmanfm's interaction with it), but if I understand correctly using it just moves the problem.
My intention is to have the background path automatically change as the background changes through pcmanfm. Whether I use the lightdm-gtk-greeter configuration file or the AccountsService you mentioned doesn't matter too much, both would probably work. The question still remains, is there a way to accomplish any one of these scenarios?

Comment: Another workaround (workaround, it is not the solution) - using some script to update AccountsService file each time pcmanfm configuration changed. http://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Or you can use script that run desktop settings app and update wallpaper after it terminates.

Comment: Hey, I guess I'll accept your answer for option 1. I will have to write a script for it myself that I'll run at startup or something.