# Why I can't install gdm login manager theme from gnome-art?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, gdm

Here is the question:

Recently I installed the ubuntu 11.04.I still use the classic gnome desktop environment with the gdm(version:2.32) login manager. and I want to change the login screen with the [cool login theme](http://art.gnome.org/themes/gdm_greeter) at the gnome art and install the gnome-art tool to install login manager themes from it. Unfortunately, its install button is gray. why ? howto ?

I just cannot fix the core of the question. According to many advices, I used some other configure tools like gnome tweak, and gdm tweaker, gdmsetup and so on. however,some of them just can change the login background with a picture, what I really need is how to install the login manager themes file(.tar.bz2 format) from the [gnome art web](http://art.gnome.org/themes/gdm_greeter).

I don't know weather you have understood it ? every answer is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The themes you are linking to appear to be for GDM version 1.x, which used to be highly themable.

GDM 1.x isn't around anymore, it's been replaced by GDM 2.x, which doesn't have the kind of theming capabilities that is shown in those screenshots.

There are still some limited theming capabilities:

- [How can I change the login screen theme in GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193/how-can-i-change-the-login-screen-theme)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just don't know why they give the limited theming capabilities in the GDM2.x.what a pity! weather there are some tools can configure it.

Comment: @lengerfulluse In 11.10 we'll use lightdm which will bring a bunch of customization options, so hang tight!