# How would one change the GDM theme in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, login-screen, gdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the login screen theme in GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193/how-can-i-change-the-login-screen-theme-in-gdm)

I am using GDM, not lightDM.

None of the established GDM login theme changers work in precise.

How can I change themes?

I can't use LightDM because it's broken in 12.04 x64 (or at least for me and some others).