# How can I replace LightDM with MDM?

Tags: lightdm, gdm

Linux Mint Cinnamon 1.4 released with "MDM display manager".  It is based on the code of GDM2.20. It provides:

- Graphical configuration tools
- Themeability
- Remote, automatic and timed login
- Event scripting
- Language selection

And it comes with more features than any other Display Manager currently available.

[image]
 (MDM)

So how can I use MDM instead of LightDM on Ubuntu?

Comment: Both display manager have some + points & - points.For now,Lightdm doesn't have support for remote login (to server) & event scripting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

If you like the GDM themeability - MDM is great!

MDM is currently part of the Linux Mint repository - after contacting the Andrew of WebUpd8.org he has also packaged this in his PPA.  Great going Andrew!

The following has been tested on 12.04 Ubuntu in a VM.  It also has been [tested independently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4747045#4747045) on 12.04 Xubuntu.

Until then (and assuming you understand the risks of using third party PPAs etc)

**from the linux mint repo**

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ maya main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list' 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring 
sudo apt-get update
```

If you see the error below - dont worry, just type **y**:

```
W: GPG error: packages.linuxmint.com maya Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3EE67F3D0FF405B2" and "WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
linuxmint-keyring
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

**from the webupd8 PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install MDM:

```
sudo apt-get install mdm mint-mdm-themes
```

During the package installation you will be asked to select between mdm and lightdm.  Using your cursor keys to select mdm and tab to **OK** and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to select.

The following error can be ignored:

```
The home directory `/var/lib/mdm' already exists. Not copying from `/etc/skel'.
adduser: Warning: The home directory `/var/lib/mdm' does not belong to the user you are currently creating.
```

Reboot.

Configure your MDM themes using:

```
gksudo mdmsetup
```

**I would strongly recommend** that after you have install mdm you immediately disable the PPA via your Software Sources because you may inadvertantly install other mint packages when you do a future update.

### how to theme

Download a GDM theme file (for example from [this website](http://gnome-look.org))

You can then use `gksudo mdmsetup` to add the `.tar.gz` archive file.

As an aside, run `mdmphotosetup` to change your *face* - in my example theme above I chose one of the stock images - the blue butterfly.

Comment: "If you see the error below - dont worry, just type y:" Ahm, no? I mean, I know what you're aiming at and that it is in this case irrelevant, but shrugging off such warnings is not a good idea. There should at least be an explanation on what this is about and why it is irrelevant *in this case*.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small tool to do the conversion from gdm to mdm. 
I hope it helps some souls :)

Download details are here - http://adhocshare.blogspot.in/2012/10/gdm2mdm-converter.html

Comment: The question is on how to switch display managers, not how to convert the themes.