# How do I change the font on the login screen?

Tags: fonts, lightdm, unity-greeter

I want to change the font in the login screen - where is the configuration for that?

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend the two best ways to change the default font of lightdm.
Open terminal and run the command `pkexec lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings` 
if it doesn't work for you, you need to install it manually using the command `sudo apt install lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings` and after installation , run  `pkexec lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings`.A window will appear where you can configure the lightdm.

[image]

Another method is to change edit the `conf` using the `dconf-editor`.
Open dconf-editor and search `greeter`from the search box

[image].

Click on the first option that appears and configure all your `lightdm` settings there.

If you don't have `dconf-editor` installed , install it by `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

This is not the answer for question asked 8 years ago but for the current users who are facing this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not bad, and cool desktop gadget/widget.

Answer (score 0):

Start by opening up a terminal, start typing "terminal" in your unity dash to see the option or press ctrl+alt+t

Lets go to the correct directory:

```
cd /etc/lightdm
```

Now lets make a backup of the file before we make any changes:

```
sudo cp unity-greeter.conf unity-greeter.conf.bak
```

Now we need to open up this file and see whats changed, type/copy this:

```
gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
```

The file should look like below:

```
#
# background = Background file to use, either an image path or a color (e.g. #772953)
# logo = Logo file to use
# theme-name = GTK+ theme to use
# font-name = Font to use
# xft-antialias = Whether to antialias Xft fonts (true or false)
# xft-dpi = Resolution for Xft in dots per inch (e.g. 96)
# xft-hintstyle = What degree of hinting to use (hintnone, hintslight, hintmedium, or hintfull)
# xft-rgba = Type of subpixel antialiasing (none, rgb, bgr, vrgb or vbgr)
#
[greeter]
background=/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
logo=/usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png
theme-name=Ambiance
icon-theme-name=ubuntu-mono-dark
font-name=Ubuntu 11
xft-antialias=true
xft-dpi=96
xft-hintstyle=hintslight
xft-rgba=rgb
```

Then save and log out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but still the default font (_Ubuntu_).

I put _Segoe 11_ (font Segoe, size 11), but has no effect on restart.

Comment: All the unity-greeter settings were moved to gsettings, at least during 12.04 and maybe before.  This info is now outdated.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to customize your Display manager lightdm may not be the ideal choice. 
I would replace it with mdm (themability, graphical configuration tools, etc) , which is a bit more bloated but you won't notice any difference except it's running on a 12 year old notebook. 
Instructions to do so can be found here: 
[How can I replace LightDM with MDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143192/how-can-i-replace-lightdm-with-mdm)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the method mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/a/224060. This command will complain "No protocol specified" but should work (omit exclamation mark in the end of the command). Though it changes only the font of the top panel in greeter.
Also you can get the list of other settings which can be adjusted with this method:

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings list-keys com.canonical.unity-greeter
```