# How to change font size of the login screen?

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my netbook with maximum resolution of 1024x600, I upgraded to ubuntu 12.10. occasionally I use other GUI because it is more comfortable to me for certain tasks. since I updated I can not switch to another GUI because I can not see and click on the OK button. how can I change the font size of the login sreen on ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue with login screen in 12.10 using a netbook, at 1024x600 resolution the OK button at bottom of the desktop environment menu is off screen. This would not be an issue if lightdm allowed configuration of font or used a scrollable menu.

Discovered a workaround, select desktop environment and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle pass other environments, the selected environment should remain highlighted with tabbing otherwise click outer edge of menu after select - <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the hidden OK button and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm selected desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks, I use the TAB and ENTER keys, additionally I use the speak option for know what option than I have selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can change part of the screen with this command, but unfortunately the entire screen doesn't respect this setting. Specifically the login box doesn't scale.  I think this is probably a bug. Here's what happened when I set the font to Ubuntu 18 (default is Ubuntu 11):

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter font-name "Ubuntu 18"!
```

[image: What it looks like with font sized to 18]