# Set scaling over the whole system

Tags: 16.04, scaling

I have a Laptop(Ubuntu 16.04) with a relative high resolution display. So to read something I set the parameter at Systemsettings -> Display -> Scaling to 1,38. This is also working fine, the problem is, the setting isn't for the whole system, it's only for the actual user. So the Loginscreen is very small where I have to type my password in and choose my user at the beginning.
How can I set the Scaling to 1,38 for the whole System?
Or at least for the loginscreen.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font size for the login screen. For example to change login screen font size from 11 points to 18 points use:

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter font-name "Ubuntu 18"!
```

Credit: [How to change font size of the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211212/how-to-change-font-size-of-the-login-screen)

Answer (score 0):

The login screen is managed and configured differently - should be lightdm? You could try this: http://lower-order.blogspot.cz/2012/11/font-size-in-lightdm.html?m=1 or just changing the lightdm settings in any other way

Comment: This config file doesnt exist in my Ubuntu system....