# Where can I find the old GDM2 Ubuntu login theme?

Tags: login-screen, gdm, display-manager

I've installed the Mint Display Manager (based on the old GDM2 code).

I'm looking for the most recent GDM2 theme that shipped with Ubuntu before they moved to LightDM, something that looks similar to this:

[image: Ubuntu old GDM2 login screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Retro themes

You can download the old GDM themes from the [old-releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/) repositories.

Your example looks like either the 8.04 GDM theme or possibly the 7.04 feisty fawn GDM theme.

- [Hardy download link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/all/ubuntu-gdm-themes/download)
- [feisty fawn gdm download link](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/edgy-gdm-themes/edgy-gdm-themes_0.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb)
- [edgy gdm download link](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/edgy-gdm-themes/edgy-gdm-themes_0.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb)

These are debian package files.  Inside the package is the *Human* GDM theme you are interested in.

To make these themes installable via `mdmsetup` you'll need to do some command-line work.

First extract the debian package:

```
dpkg -x [packagename] gdm
```

Next navigate to the Human theme folder

```
cd gdm/usr/share/gdm/themes/
```

Now lets create an archive file:

```
tar -cvf Human.tar Human
gzip Human.tar
```

This will create a `.tar.gz` file in this folder.

Run `gksudo mdmsetup` and navigate to this folder to locate the new archive file and install the theme.

This is the result in my virtualbox session using the feisty GDM package:

[image: pic]

---

Linked Question:

- [How can I replace LightDM with MDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143192/how-can-i-replace-lightdm-with-mdm/143201#143201)