# MDM doesn't automatically start

Tags: installation, 13.04, lightdm

I just successfully installed mdm on 13.04 with this guide, replacing but not uninstalling lightdm: [How can I replace LightDM with MDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143192/how-can-i-replace-lightdm-with-mdm).

However, when I first rebooted, I just got a blank screen. I booted into recovery, and switched back to lightdm and booted back.

I did `sudo mdm` and immediately it went to the default mdm login screen. But upon reboot, it again gave a blank screen.

So back in recovery, I ran `mdm` as root, and same thing, except upon logging in there was no network connection nor sound (which I understand because it was still in recovery).

I'm not sure why mdm isn't automatically starting with boot, but lightdm still works. Is there any way to get mdm to start the way it should?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What does `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` give you? It should provide you an option to start MDM at boot (along with other display managers).

Comment: I did `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` to change the default back to lightdm, and it works successfully. I used `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm` to change it back to mdm while booted in. Neither gives any errors.
However, running `sudo mdmconfig` doesn't work after having run either, unless I also run `sudo mdm`

Answer (score 1):

If you have Infinality fonts installed, try uninstallign them as there's reports around that loading them before MDM causes problems:

https://superuser.com/questions/558974/linux-mint-fails-to-start-x-automatically-after-update-but-x-still-works

[MDM doesn't automatically start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311598/mdm-doesnt-automatically-start/393643#393643)

---

I personally don't and am experiencing the same thing with 13.10 minus the network trouble.

I've only done couple things besides a plain update so it's strange others aren't having this issue, so lets compare; did you recently install Wine or install / installant Mono?

If this really is font related wine seems like the more likely suspect as I know I had problems with fonts there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been up all day trying to fix an error that I think is very similar to this. I searched all the related help sources to find out why MDM was not booting except when run with sudo (as in, it fails on boot and I enter terminal using alt-F6 and I type sudo mdm), and I found the following command fixes it:

```
sudo update-rc.d mdm defaults
```

Furthermore, back when I had to run mdm using sudo, my audio wouldn't work. Now after running the above command and having a proper boot, the audio works again.

Just as a caveat, I don't really know what I'm doing so it's not like I identified the problem in all its generality. On the other hand, I don't think there's any harm in running the above command because it's setting something or other to default.