# How to chabge GDM Login theme in ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, themes, lts, gdm

I have ubuntu 12.04 lts and I changed my login screen to GDM by typing

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

how do I change the theme in ubuntu 12.04? I downloaded a theme using gnome-look.org. Where do I extract the theme and how do I apply it?

Answer (score -1):

Although this will change gdm by mdm this works and has been tested on 12.04.
[How can I replace LightDM with MDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143192/how-can-i-replace-lightdm-with-mdm)

Comment: Errrhm, *GDM*...

Comment: I want to know that HOW DO YOU CHANGE THE GDM THEME, NOT THE UNITY THEME.