# How to apply theme?

Tags: themes, gdm

I'm trying to apply the following theme: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/H4k3r?content=156969

I have a .themes folder in "Home" folder but Ubuntu Tweak Tool won't detect it. Running 13.04

Comment: 13.04 uses LDM by default. That is for GDM: "Hi, I made this **GDM** themefor my Linux Mint 14. I like hacker-terminal look and feel so i tried to make this theme like that only. Feel free to use it." Also, I'm not sure whether ~/.themes would be the correct place.

Comment: So basically, there's no way of applying this theme?

Comment: No idea. I've never tried to theme the DM; that's why I wrote "_I'm not sure_". Wait till someone who knows comes around. But read the tag description for GDM. That tells you that GDM isn't being used in 13.04 as default.

Answer (score 1):

That is a theme for GNOME's login and display manager. Since Ubuntu uses LightDM by default, you would need to install GDM to replace it. During installation, you should be asked to choose one, because there can be only one. I don't know if this is a very good idea, because there is a slight chance that the Unity desktop relies on some feature of LightDM.

A quick search indicated that GDM has a configuration manager that allows you to browse your files and select the theme from there. If that doesn't work for you, then look at [How can I change the login screen theme in GDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193/how-can-i-change-the-login-screen-theme-in-gdm?rq=1)