# How to change the color of the 'Incorrect Password' text

Tags: 16.04, unity, lightdm, login-screen

I want to be able to change the 'Incorrect Password' text to a different color in the lightdm login screen, but I can't figure out how.  I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Unity 7.4, and I have the following programs installed:

- Default system settings
- Unity tweak tool
- Ubuntu tweaks
- CCSM
- dconf editor

I can't find an option to change the text color anywhere, so if someone could help me out that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Which text are you talking about? Where and when does it appear?

Comment: @Zanna I guess OP wants to change the one in unity-greeter of Lightdm login screen. But there is still little doubt. @ OP Please mention whether or not you're using the default login screen of Ubuntu

Comment: @Anwar, yes I'm using the default login screen.  My apologies for the confusion

Comment: unity-greeter will be your login screen. check this https://code.launchpad.net/unity-greeter

Comment: @ShaurabhBharti i dont understand what that is, perhaps make an answer explaining it?

Comment: He sent you a link to the source code of the unity-greeter, so you can find the thing you want to change there, build it and deploy on your system. That's what I get out of his comment it at least.

Comment: I don't know how to do any of that so an explanation would be much appreciated

Comment: I would suggest asking the developers of the unity greeter if you can't look into the code yourself. It seems the font colors aren't changable by regular tools - that must mean it is build in somewhere, like an error color. They probably can help you quicker.

Comment: @Ziazis I actually checked the codebase but couldn't find it. It is also possible that the color data is picked from theme and not stored in unity-greeter.

Comment: @Shaurabh, still faster to ask the devs themselfe since they'll know what they use.

Comment: @Ziazis yes absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile `unity-greeter` for that. Here is how to do it.

#### Download the source

Download the unity-greeter package source for Xenial from (the one with `.tar.xz` extension) here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/unity-greeter and extract it into your home directory.

#### Change the source

Now open the file `src/prompt-box.vala` and go to the line no. `438` The relevant area of the source will be like this

```vala
...
        Gdk.RGBA color = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
        if (is_error)
            color.parse ("#df382c");
        label.override_color (Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, color);
...
```

Now change the hex value of the color to your desired value. I used `#33A0FF` to test it.

#### Recompile

Now you need to recompile it. You may need development packages to do so. I needed these package to install `libindicator-dev libido3-0.1-dev liblightdm-gobject-1-dev libindicator3-dev libunity-settings-daemon-dev unity-settings-daemon-dev`

All dependency requirements can be fulfilled by installing these packages

```
sudo apt install autoconf-archive gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-ido3-0.1 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gnome-common gnome-desktop3-data gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev libcanberra-dev libcanberra0 libdbus-glib-1-dev libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgnome-desktop-3-dev libgtk2.0-dev libido3-0.1-dev libindicator-dev libindicator3-dev libindicator7 liblightdm-gobject-1-dev libtdb1 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libvorbisfile3 libxkbfile-dev libxklavier-dev sound-theme-freedesktop unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk3-module unity-settings-daemon-dev xvfb
```

Now, go to the root of the extracted folder and use these commands sequentically to build

```
./autogen.sh
make
```

If first command complains about some missing packages or header files, you need to research which package may contain that header file. Usually the package name would be something starting with the `lib` prefix and ending with `-dev` suffix and contain the name of the file that was missing.

Once you successfully make the build, install it using

```
sudo make install
```

Now just login and see the effect!

Here is a screenshot after I modified the text color (taken using `dm-tool`)

[image: lightdm unity greeter error color change]

Answer (score -1):

Short of rebuilding lightdm, you can't change the 'Incorrect Password' text or its colour as lightdm uses hardcoded messages. Running

```
sudo -u lightdm dbus-launch gsettings list-keys com.canonical.unity-greeter
```

gives you the list of settings which you can change. GDM and MDM have themes which may support changing the colour of the alert.

Comment: can you please edit answer to include the details of what GDM and MDM are and how to use them?

Comment: GDM is the GNOME Display Manager whereas MDM is for Mint. I didn't add more info as I have very less experience with them. `sudo apt-get install gdm` installs gdm. Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193/how-can-i-change-the-login-screen-theme-in-gdm) to see how you can add themes to gdm.

Comment: ty - will try this